# Is it possible to mark a store field as readonly in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, properties, readonly

In ExtJS, I have a `JsonStore` configured like this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // basic properties
    restful: true,
    autoSave: true,

    // json writer
    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        writeAllFields: true
    }),

    // field config
    fields: [
        'id',
        'name',
        { name: 'timestamp', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' }
    ]
});
```

The `timestamp` property should be set by the server, and the client should only read it. However, if I try to add or update a record using the `JsonStore`:

```
// add a record
var record = new store.recordType({ name: 'New record' });
store.insert(0, record);

// update a record
var record = store.getAt(0);
record.set('name', 'Modified record');
```

The JSON that's being sent over to the server looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Modified record",
    "timestamp": "01-06-2001T15:23:14"
}
```

I'd like it to stop sending over the `timestamp` property, since it's supposed to be read-only. Is there any way of configuring either the store or the record in order to get this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Since Ext4 you may use

```
persist: false
```

in the Model field description

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.namespace('Ext.ux');

/**
 * Extension of the JsonWriter that doesn't send fields having the config option
 * write set to false
 * @author Friedrich Röhrs
 * @verison 1.0
 *
 */
Ext.ux.AdvJsonWriter = function (config) {
    Ext.ux.AdvJsonWriter.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
Ext.extend(Ext.ux.AdvJsonWriter, Ext.data.JsonWriter, /** @lends Ext.ux.AdvJsonWriter */{
    toHash: function(rec, options) {
        var map = rec.fields.map,
            data = {},
            raw = (this.writeAllFields === false && rec.phantom === false) ? rec.getChanges() : rec.data,
            m;
        Ext.iterate(raw, function(prop, value){
            if((m = map[prop])){
                if (m.write !== false)
                    data[m.mapping ? m.mapping : m.name] = value;
            }
        });
        // we don't want to write Ext auto-generated id to hash.  Careful not to remove it on Models not having auto-increment pk though.
        // We can tell its not auto-increment if the user defined a DataReader field for it *and* that field's value is non-empty.
        // we could also do a RegExp here for the Ext.data.Record AUTO_ID prefix.
        if (rec.phantom) {
            if (rec.fields.containsKey(this.meta.idProperty) && Ext.isEmpty(rec.data[this.meta.idProperty])) {
                delete data[this.meta.idProperty];
            }
        } else {
            data[this.meta.idProperty] = rec.id;
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

then

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // basic properties
    restful: true,
    autoSave: true,

    // json writer
    writer: new Ext.ux.AdvJsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        writeAllFields: true
    }),

    // field config
    fields: [
        'id',
        'name',
        { name: 'timestamp', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c', write: false }
    ]
});
```

the timestamp field will never be send to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you set {disabled: true} on the timestamp field, it shouldn't be submitted to server

Comment: You're referring to an `Ext.form.Field`, whereas I'm referring to an `Ext.data.Field`. The example code I provided clearly shows that I do not use a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default value to whatever you want on the timestamp field.  You have configured your JsonWriter to go ahead and write to all fields.  If you set the default value to '' or NULL you might be able to get the desired behavior you want.

Comment: Setting it to null will still send the property over, just with a null value instead. I think that I'll have to override the default behavior of either the `JsonStore` or the `Record` to include a `readonly` config property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try intercepting the call to the writer and just remove the timestamp at that time:

```
var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
    encode: false,
    writeAllFields: true
});

Ext.intercept(writer, 'render', function(params, baseParams, data) {
    delete data.timestamp;
});

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
...
writer: writer,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `writeAllFields` have to be `true`? It defaults to `false` which wouldn't send the timestamp property if you didn't update it.

Alternatively, you could override the [`toHash`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DataWriter.html#method-Ext.data.DataWriter-toHash) function on the `JsonWriter`. At the moment it has this comment:

```
TODO Implement excludes/only configuration with 2nd param
```

You could add your own implementation of that.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be true because the REST service I'm using does a replace. If I don't send over a property, it assumes that the property is null and will save it to the database as such, overwriting and previous values.

Comment: That should've been "any previous values", not "and previous values".

Comment: Ah. Override `toHash` then, I reckon.